# isolate for variable in equation with the ti 84+ ti basic

Tags: ti-basic

I am making a system of equations solver. it works great, but I can't input any equation.
It needs to already have the right side be y=
so I can't do:

```
2x + 5y = 19
x -2y  = -4
```

I have to simplify to:

```
y = (19 - 2x)/5
y = (-4 - x)/-2
```

Is there any way to turn the 1st group of equations into the 2nd one and isolate variable y?
I have been trying to come up with a solution, but nothing comes to mind.

Comment: You need a function  that converts a string of type `nx + my = p`  to `y = (p - nx) / m`?